# regular expression wrapping words

Tags: java, regex

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me with a regular expression to do the following.

The rules:

- all words except 'and' need wrapping with SYN()
- the String can contain an unlimited amount of words, the same rules appyl to all of the words in the String.

Examples:

'London and toilet' to become 'SYN(London) and SYN(toilet)'

'10 and Mayfield and London' would become '10 and SYN(Mayfield) and SYN(London)' (10 is not wrapped as it is not a word)

The reason for my question is that I am using an ORACLE thesaurus and the SQL syntax requires words to be wrapped with SYN().

I was initially going to split all of the words up in the String by searching for spaces and then using String.format(SYN(%s), ‘London’) to wrap the word in SYN() but I knew that all of this could be done with a regular expression and I thought that there would be some eager regular expression fanatics who would  help me out.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place for **questions**, not requests for people to write code for you. (There *are* places for that, this just isn't one of them.) See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Comment: I do not quite understand the rules. Why isn’t it `SYN(10) and SYN(Mayfield) and SYN(London)`? Does it only apply to the last two words of an unlimited length list? Does it not apply to numbers?

Comment: You know what? It *is* the holiday season, after all, so I'll be generous. For only $40/hour (minimum time billed of two hours, both of which must be paid up-front), I'll code this for you. Do you have PayPal?

Comment: I was going to down the route of splitting the String up into individual words then using .format(“SYN(%s) “address”)  on the String object but I knew that there would be a better way to do it.

Comment: Aufziehvogel - The reason why it wouldnt be SYN(10) and SYN(Mayfield) and SYN(London) is because only words and not digits need wrapping. There can be an unknwon amount of words and the same rules need applying to all. I am using an ORACLE thesaurus so that is why i am wrapping words with SYN(). Sorry if this wasnt clear to everyone but atleast Evgeniy Dorofeev could understand what i was asking and provided a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println("10 and Mayfield and London".replaceAll("(\\p{Alpha}+)", "SYN($1)").replace("SYN(and)", "and"));
```

output

```
10 and SYN(Mayfield) and SYN(London)
```

Comment: Evgeniy Dorofeev - that works great thanks.